# How to change the nth byte in a file without loading it into RAM using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, time-complexity, big-o

Is there any way to change the nth byte of a file with a O(1) space and time complexity. I do know a way to read the nth byte (without loading to RAM) with a O(n) time complexity by adding a newline every x characters and iterating over the lines in the file.

Notes:
I have a .txt file ~1GB in size using latin-1 encoding (So each character taking up 1byte).

Comment: Why don't you just seek to the position in the file buffer and read the following byte? This will not require to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: Unless your file is on an inherently serial medium like a physical tape you simply open the file, [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to byte `n`, write the new byte, and close the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can change the current file position to a specific location within the file, then you can overwrite the next byte.

```
with open("blankpaper.txt", "wb") as f:
    # write a few bytes to file
    f.write(b"abcdefg")
    # changes file position
    f.seek(3)
    # overwrites the fourth byte
    f.write(b"g")
```

The resulting file has contents `b"abcgefg"`.